# Consequences of deprecated Camera class

Tags: android, deprecated, surfaceholder

Changed my code from using deprecated Camera class to CameraDevice and now have the errors indicated ("<-- here"). What is the best alternative for replacing these parameters?
Looking at the documentation it seems that, at least for the orientation, a sensor is the appropriate option but that seems an overly complicated response.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); <-- here
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); <-- here
        mCamera.startPreview(); <-- here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview(); <-- here
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder); <-- here
        mCamera.startPreview(); <-- here

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```